# Find the remainder when $2^{2019}$ is divided by $2019$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

This question is from Jmo odisha 2019. I used fermat's theorem but it did not work as 2019 is a composite number. Then how do I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $2019=3\times673$

Comment: Hint : $2019 = 3 \times 673$ is the product of two primes. Now, find $2^{2019} \mod 3$ and $\mod 673$ using Fermat's little theorem. Use the Chinese remainder theorem to find the remainder mod $2019$ (as the unique positive integer smaller than $2019$ leaving those remainders mod $3$ and $673$), which must be the answer. (You can do this case-by-case since $3$ is a small number).

Comment: an analogous problem could have been asked in $1983=3\times661$

Comment: $$a^{2b + c} \equiv (a^b)^2a^c \pmod c$$ Since $\log_2 2019 < 11$ you have to compute a modular squaring at most 11 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $2^{1344}\equiv1\bmod2019$, so $2^{2019}\equiv2^{675}\bmod2019$.

By Fermat's little theorem, $2^{672}\equiv1\bmod673$, so $2^{675}\equiv2^3=8\bmod673$.

Also $2^{675}\equiv2^1\equiv2^3=8\bmod3$.

Therefore, by the Chinese remainder theorem, $2^{675}\equiv8\bmod2019$.

---

More generally, if $p>3$ is prime, then $p$ divides $2^{p-1}-1,$ and $3$ divides $2^{p-1}-1,$

so $3p$ divides $2^{p-1}-1$, so $3p$ divides $2^{3p-3}-1$, so $3p$ divides $2^{3p}-8$.

Answer (score 1):

Or, $2^{2019}\cong2\pmod3$ and $2^{2019}\cong2^3\pmod{673}$, both by little fermat.

Then since $2\cong2^3\pmod3$, we can use the constant case of the Chinese remainder theorem.

Thus $2^{2019}\cong8\pmod{2019}$.